# How to disable trash?

Tags: centos, rhel, gnome

This is a nice and straightforward question: how can I disable the Trash Can in Gnome running on CentOS/RHEL 6.4?

I know I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Del</kbd> to bypass the Trash; but how can I completely disable it?

Or otherwise, how can I remap <kbd>Del</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>?

Comment: You probably don't want to remap the del key.

Comment: @don_crissti What command can I run to get that? It's up to date with `yum` anyway.

Comment: @don_crissti `-bash: gnome-shell: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

Run `dconf-editor`, and open:

org -> gnome -> desktop -> interface

Enable "can-change-accels".

Open `nautilus`, select any file/directory, then click "Edit" from menubar, and hover on "Move to Trash" menuitem. While hovering, click on your delete key. The accel should change from "ctrl+del" to "del".

Make sure you have selected a file, else the "Move to Trash" menuitem will be greyed out.

**NOTE:** I suggest you disable "can-change-accels" afterwards, to prevent accidental accel changes.

If the above doesn't work take a look at this [archlinux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Changing_hotkeys) on how to change your hotkeys in Gnome 3.x. This article has specific steps for a couple of versions of Nautilus.

Comment: What this does is changing the accel for `<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash` to `DEL`. It does not bypass the `Trash`.

Comment: Did you try the other method mentioned in the archlinux wiki?

Comment: I get `-bash: dconf-editor: command not found` when running `dconf-editor` and `No package dconf-editor available` with `yum install dconf-editor`.

Comment: Use `gconf-editor` if you do not have `dconf-editor`, `yum install gconf-editor`, if it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the real solution is to create a custom-compiled version of `libgio` (» [GIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software))) which is modified to call `g_file_delete()` every time an application calls `g_file_trash()`.

A step-by-step guide on *GitHub* can be found here:

[Globally disable GNOME's Trash in Debian-based distributions](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Cordic77/libgio-disable-trash/blob/master/Globally%20disable%20GNOME's%20Trash%20in%20Debian-based%20distributions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

*According to the [archlinux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Changing_hotkeys) slm mentioned,* in file `~/.config/nautilus/accels` find the following line:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Delete" "<Shift>Delete")
```

and replace it with:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Delete" "Delete")
```

Then kill nautilus to apply the changes:

```
killall nautilus
```

Please note you still can move the file to the trash using `CTRL` + `delete`.

*Tested on Fedora 18 with GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1*