# Set specific umask for .Trash-* folder

Tags: linux, umask, shared-folders, trash

We are working on CentOS and our data servers are running FreeNAS.
We have a few shared projects automounted in `/shared_projects` folder.

Each times a user delete a file in those shared projects, it results in the creation of a `.Trash-uid` folder at the root of this specific project.
This means that we can have a lot of `.Trash-*` folder in all those shared projects. This can become a real mess.

```
/shared_projects/projectA/.Trash-uid1
/shared_projects/projectA/.Trash-uid2
/shared_projects/projectA/.Trash-uid3
/shared_projects/projectB/.Trash-uid1
....
```

Cleaning all those folders requires a lot of time since permissions of those trashes are owner only.
Each time we want to clean those, we need to ssh as root onto the specific server, remove those file. Same for next server...

Is there a way to force a different umask for those Trash folders? That will allow us to clean them from one workstation without root permissions.

EDIT:
Umask is already set for all users to `0002` but trashes don't follow it.
Projects are shared through NFS.

Answer (score 0):

How file are pushed/deleted from the FreeNAS by users ?

If it's by mounting it locally (using NFS, CIFS or any other remote filesystem), then you have to configure the `umask` on each workstation.
You may also simply disable the trash feature, see [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71547/how-to-disable-trash)

If it's using a service running on FreeNAS (FTP/sFTP/...), then you have to set the umask before starting the service.

Instead of trying to fix the `umask`, you would better create a `cron` task to automatize the cleanup of these directories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, it's shared by NFS FreeNAS service. Umask is properly setted for all users but not respected for trashes. Cron is a solution, that's true but I would prefer open permissions.

Comment: Can you clarify "Umask is properly setted for all users" ? Where is it set ?

Comment: Yes, all users source the same setup and umask is set in it.

Comment: Maybe you can force umask on the mountpoint directly into the `/etc/fstab` ...

Comment: I've just tested it and it's not solving the problem. It looks like trashes are ignoring umask.